# Smart Watch - record and playback audio without phone?

Tags: smart-device

I'm looking for a smartwatch, that can record and playback audio, without a phone, as I don't have one.

#### I'd also prefer that it

- have an app store, development kit available, e.g. ios, android wear, or tizen make sense
- < $200
- vibration support
- speaker
- microphone

I find so many of these watches want you to have a phone - e.g. the Pebble Time.

Comment: Would something like a Samsung Gear S2 3g be along the lines of what you are looking for? It has a microphone and a speaker.

Comment: That's appears to be an option for sure... Thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting an Asus Zenwatch 2, as it has a mic and a speaker, and can record audio on the watch, without a phone nearby.

The app I'm using so far is [Watch Recorder with Mic Zoom](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tamalbasak.watchrecorder), which lets you record and playback multiple audio files on the watch without a phone.